# How to enable the WMI service on many machines to find MS-Office licenses using the Volume Activation Management Tool 2.0 using Active Directory?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, license, active-directory, vamt

I installed the `Volume Activation Management Tool 2.0` from Microsoft to scan all the computers on my network to find out how many valid MS Office licenses we have installed on all of the machines.

Every workstation should have MS-Office installed on it, but not all of them are registered.  Unfortunately I'm not sure that every workstation in the place is configured to pickup the  licenses.   I've gotten alot of `Unable to connect to the WMI service on the remote machine` errors.  Okay so obviously it's the WMI service, is there any way of batch-enabling  on the network?

Answer (score 0):

Either use an account with local admin on all machines or follow [these directions](https://support.infosim.net/demo/wmi/wmi.htm) to create an account with remote wmi access only.

I have used both VAMT 2.0 and 3.0 and I find that 3.0 is far more useful as it maintains a database you can query for licensing and can also store keys.